# SelectedIndex não funciona

Tags: javascript, html-select

Estou validando um pequeno formulário e não consigo fazer isso usando a propriedade `selectedIndex`.

Código que não está funcionando:

```js
const movimento_loja = window.document.getElementById('movi')


function camposPreenchidos() {
    if (objetivo_mensal.value.length == 0) {
        objetivo_mensal.focus()
        return false
    } else if (valor_venda.value.length == 0) {
        valor_venda.focus()
        return false
    } else if (movimento_loja.selectedIndex == 0) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="mv" id="movi">
    <option value="movimento">Movimento da loja hoje</option>
    <option value="ninguem">Ninguém entrando</option>
    <option value="gato-pingado">Só gato-pingado</option>
    <option value="normal">Fluxo normal</option>
    <option value="fluindo">Tá fluindo</option>
    <option value="explodiu">Explodiu!</option>
</select>
```

Só consegui resolver o problema usando a propriedade `value` do `movimento_loja`, assim:

```
function camposPreenchidos() {
    if (objetivo_mensal.value.length == 0) {
        objetivo_mensal.focus()
        return false
    } else if (valor_venda.value.length == 0) {
        valor_venda.focus()
        return false
    } else if (movimento_loja.value == 'movimento') {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Gostaria de entender melhor o porquê, pois, mesmo tendo resolvido o problema, sinto que não entendi completamente a razão do erro.

Comment: O que é `objetivo_mensal`?

Comment: Eu testei aqui e a propriedade `selectIndex` funciona normalmente. Tente detalhar a sua resposta um pouco mais para que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @LuizFelipe é um input tipo Number. Bem como valor_venda. Porém movimento_loja é uma combobox que vem com valor padrão 'Movimento da loja hoje' e o usuário deve trocar para um valor válido. Equivale a um campo vazio, apenas para evitar que o usuário mande um valor padrão válido sem escolher de fato.